# Macro to copy a row to new Columns if cell marked complete

Tags: vba, excel

Im trying to learn how to write a macro for when cells in column H are marked "Complete" it copies the entire row and pastes it in a new page called "complete" and deletes the row from my current page.

I tried recording it myself but kept breaking it. I have no clue if I'm doing this right.

This is my code so far:

```
Sub Completed_Move()
    ' Completed_Move
    Macro Dim srchrng As Range, row As Range

    Set srchrng = Range("H1,H500")
    'For each cel in srchrng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value) = Complete Then
        Activecell.Offset(0, -7).Range("A1:N1").Select
        Selection.Cut
        Sheets("Completed").Select
        Activecell.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste Sheets("Current").Select
        Activecell.Rows("2:1").EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Activecell.Offset(2, 7).Range("A1").Select
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code you have? How are you "breaking it"? Do you get errors (if so, what errors, where)?  Please show what you've tried so far, and we can help guide you.

Comment: I recorded the macro for the copy and paste portion but when I did that it only copied and pasted the active cell. The error I get is "Expected End Sub" I then tried to create a search range for column H and added an If Then after that.

Comment: @CameronAlexander : Please take a second to take the [tour] (click it) to learn how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in comments, if you have an error message as explicit as this one :

> Expected End Sub

which means that your code is missing an `End Sub` to close the sub! Just add it at the end of your code.

---

Here is your code (with `End Sub`...), improved :

```
Sub Completed_Move()
    'Completed_Move Macro
    Dim SrchRng As Range, RowRg As Range, CellRg As Range
    Dim wS1 As Worksheet, wSC As Worksheet
    Dim i as Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wS1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set wSC = .Sheets("Completed")
    End With 'ThisWorkbook

    Set SrchRng = wS1.Range("H1:H500")
    For i = SrchRng.Cells(SrchRng.Rows.Count,1).Row To SrchRng.Cells(1,1).Row Step -1
        'If "Complete" is part of value in H
        If InStr(1, SrchRng.Cells(i,1).Value, "Complete") Then
            With wSC
                wS1.Range("A" & SrchRng.Cells(i,1).Row & ":N" & SrchRng.Cells(i,1).Row).Copy .Range("A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End With 'wSC
            SrchRng.Cells(i,1).Rows("2:1").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: But if you are looping forwards you are missing back to back matches, since you are deleting a row, and the next row gets the row number of the present row you just scanned and deleted, isn't so ?

Comment: @ShaiRado : Thx for waking me up, I just used the base of OP and didn't thought of it! ;) I'll correct in a bit! ;)

Comment: ok, so I can start understanding this more... what Shai is saying is that when I run this it will miss back to back rows that are completed. is that because of the last command? CellRg.Rows("2:1").EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: @CameronAlexander : That's right, because it'll look on the next row after deleting, but what was the next row (let's say at N+1) will be on the same row (N) after the deletion.

Comment: @R3uK  just leave the deleting part to the end, save all rows in array and then delete them all at once

Comment: @CameronAlexander : See the edit, to avoid the issue of missing something because of deletion. Or try to implement the method that Shai Rado suggested (which is more efficient ;) )

Comment: @ShaiRado : I'll let him try that himself! ;) My brain is starting to malfunction, I've done too much [tag:progress-4gl]!^^

Comment: I appreciate your help I think I got it from here!